# Bitwise Operation on 2 numbers to always produce unique result?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Can I rely on any permutation of a bitwise operation to always produce a unique result? Bitwise operations have always been my weak point.

My goal is to `OR` 2 numbers to always produce a unique value. And one of the numbers will always be constant (equal `0x0111`). Ie,

```
int uniqueDelegateId1 = WM_COMMAND | btn1.id; // resolves to 0x0111 | 50008
int uniqueDelegateId2 = WM_COMMAND | btn2.id; // resolves to 0x0111 | 50009
```

The above example doesn't produce unique results, both produce `50009`. Could I use a different bitwise operator to ensure I always get a unique result? Such as xor, and, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why you can't just use the `id` value.

If you need to distinguish between multiple message/id combinations, you can shift one of the values out of the other's range before ORing them together, along the lines of

`WM_COMMAND | (btn1.id << MAX_COMMAND_BIT_WIDTH)`